# DC/OS scaling of clusters on Azure

Tags: azure, dcos

I've installed DC/OS via the Azure Container Service (ACS), but I can't find any information anywhere on how to either scale this manually (just increase the number of agents), or ideally automatically in response to load.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways you can scale an ACS cluster:

CLI: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azurelinux/2016/07/20/azure-cli-0-10-2-release-update-5th-july-2016/

ACS resource provider: simply resubmit your ARM template for ACS with a new number of agents.

VMSS: use the portal to configure the scale set (including autoscale) https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview/